# Mapping in reference to a metric space (terminology question)

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, terminology

Let the pair $( S, d \, )$ be a metric space, i.e.
$d\!: S^2 \rightarrow R$, where for any three distinct elements $k$, $p$, $q$ $\in S$:
$d[ \, p, q \, ] = d[ \, q, p \, ] > 0$,
$d[ \, p, q \, ] + d[ \, q, k \, ] \geq d[ \, p, k \, ]$, and
$d[ \, p, p \, ] = 0$.

My question concerns a (any) set $X$, and

a (any) map $x\!: S^2 \rightarrow X$
which satisfies that there exists an element $z_{X}$ $\in X$ such that
for each element $p$ $\in S$: $ x[ \, p, p \, ] = z_{X} $ and
for any two distinct elements $p$, $q$ $\in S$: $ x[ \, p, q \, ] \ne z_{X} $, and

a map $r_d\!: (X \verb|\| z_{X})^2 \rightarrow R$ which is defined such that
for any two not necessarily distinct elements $a$, $b$ $\in (X \verb|\| z_{X})$
and for any four not necessarily all distinct elements $j$, $k$, $p$, $q$ $\in S$ such that
$ x[ \, j, k \, ] = a $ and $ x[ \, p, q \, ] = b $
the values of map $r_d$ are defined as
$ r_d[ \, a, b \, ] := d[ \, j, k \, ] / d[ \, p, q \, ] $.

Note that the pair $( S, x \, )$ is not necessarily a metric space since set $X$ is not necessarily the set of real numbers, $R$; nor necessarily some subset of $R$.

I'd like to know:
How do you call such a set $X$, or such maps $x$ or $r_d$, in general, please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain that all of the conditions you mention in your "definition" are satisfied in this setting, but I think you should look at $\Gamma$-Ultrametric spaces, c.f. [notes by Ackerman](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~nate/papers/paper_3/paper_3.pdf), where $\Gamma$ is a complete lattice with minimal element (denoted 0 for convenience) and the map $d_M: M \times M \rightarrow \Gamma$ is a $\Gamma$-ultrametric.

Answer (score 2):

Many examples can be obtained by the following scheme: Let $x$ assign to each pair $(p,q)$ in $S$ either the fixed element $z_X$ if $p=q$, or, if $p\neq q$, some entity that encodes the distance $d(p,q)$ along with some other information about $(p,q)$.  Let $X$ be the set of all such encodings and $z_X$.  Define $r_d$ to be the function which, given two encodings, decodes them, extracts the metric values (discarding the additional information), and produces the ratio of those distances.  For example, if $S$ is the plane, $x(p,q)$ could be the vector $p-q$, where the additional information encoded is the direction.

Because of the great variety of options for the additional information (for various particular metric spaces $S$) as well as the great variety of options for the encoding scheme, I would doubt that this general concept has acquired a name.  Note also, that the additional information could be chosen in perverse ways and still satisfy your definition.  For example, in the case of the plane, I could take $x(p,q)$ to be the vector $p-q$ as above when this points into the upper half-plane but just $d(p,q)$ otherwise.  So it seems to me that your definition is too broad to give a natural concept.

It also seems to me that such "encodings of distances plus other information" are the only examples satisfying your definition.  Or do you have essentially different ones?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jeremy and Andreas, for your comments.
In the notes by Ackerman (http://www.math.upenn.edu/~nate/papers/paper_3/paper_3.pdf) already the first paragraph has the clue:

> *[...] the distance function takes values in a fixed complete lattice (and not necessarily in the reals)*

. What I had not imagined when asking my question was that people would speak of a "*distance function*" in such a case at all, and not at least for instance of a "generalized distance function"; considering that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_function (which redirects to [[Metric space]]) and even http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#General_case specificly require that any distance function should take values in the reals.
(Or could you perhaps suggest another online reference for terminology than Wikipedia?)

So a generalization of the notion "distance function" (perhaps even the essential generalization) is apparently achieved by generalizing its codomain from the reals, $R$, to

> [... the triple] $(\Gamma, \leq, 0)$ [which is] a complete lattice with minimal element 0

(cmp. Definition 1.1 of Ackerman's paper).

There's an additional point to my question, though, which I now can try to express more specificly -- perhaps:

What exactly is required to **induce** a partial order "$\leq$" in a given set $X$ or $\Gamma$?

I suppose: some particular relation (or collection of relations) to some other, already given partially ordered set(s); i.e. something that may well be called an "*encoding*" (although I don't know if that's a precise, technical term, of course ...)

p.s.
There are only 600 characters available for a comment?!?
And it can't even be formatted sensibly? ...
Sorry -- then I rather reply by posting an "Answer" than trying to "comment".